# How to mock Class<Out T> for JUnit Test

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito, mockk

How can I mock `Class<Out T>` ? I get therer error : Mockito match any class argument when I try to mock and use it in a

`whenever(mockClass.method(mockClass)).thenReturns(...)`

`any(Class::class)` or `any(Class::class.java)` didn't help either.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What code are you trying? What exactly is the error?

Comment: Why do you need to mock a class object? I think you can use `eq(Someclass::class)` to get what you need.